# Is there a downside for running docker experimental features?

Tags: docker, container, docker-compose

I know that Docker allows enabling experimental features on the daemon side in a rather simple way:

Add/update `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```bsh
{
"experimental": true
}
```

And enabling experimental features brings a couple of cool things (e.g. Metrics (Prometheus) output for basic container, image, and daemon operations)

My question is what are exactly the dangers of enabling experimental features? Because they're not enable by default and I assume they are not ok for production environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the Docker Experimental Features description](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/README.md):

> Experimental features are **not** ready for production. They are provided for test and evaluation in your sandbox environments.

This confirms your suspicion without really explaining it. In general, experimental features are labeled as such for at least one of the following reasons:

- they’re not complete;
- they’re not fully tested (put another way, they’re buggy);
- their user interface isn’t finalised;
- their usefulness is still being assessed.

Even assuming well-tested experimental features, the reason they shouldn’t be *relied* upon in production is that there is absolutely no guarantee that they will remain as-is in future versions. This means that if you end up relying on them, you *could* end up in a situation where for example you need to upgrade to a newer release (to fix security issues) but that release changes an experimental feature in a backwards-incompatible fashion, or even drops it entirely.